# Replace zeros in the data frame with average values of adjacent rows in the same column

Tags: python, pandas

I have imported data from excel file into a variable df using pandas. Some of the values are zeros. I need to replace this values with the average of the values in the upper row and lower row of the same column. Please suggest how I can iterate and calculate the average values.

Answer (score 1):

use `intrpolate` after replacing 0s with NaNs

```
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'A' : [2,3,0,1]})
df.replace(0,np.nan, inplace = True)
df.interpolate(inplace=True)
df
```

this returns

```
    A
0   2.0
1   3.0
2   2.0
3   1.0
```

Comment: intrpolate works,Thank you! I want to know if we can do it in another way using for loop and iterrows. This would help me in understanding loop iteration better

Comment: It is generally highly recommended to avoid iterating over Pandas rows/columns if you can avoid it, for performance reasons. But if you insist, you can get access to the underlying data as a numpy array via `data = df.values` and then you can loop over the 2D array `data` to your heart's content